# How to position 2 divs within a larger one?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to recreate this: [image]
However, I'm having trouble positioning everything. What's the best way to go through this?

Current HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div id="interview">
          <h1>INTERVIEW: JOHN HUNT</h1>
        </div>
      <div id="article">
        <h2>ARTICLE: WOMEN IN SURFING</h2>
      </div>
</div>
```

Current CSS:

```
#container{
width:918px;
height:429px;
background-color:#cdcccc;
clear:both;}

.wrap{
width: 620px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-top:10px;}

#interview{
width:652px;
height:179px;
background-color:#FFF;}

#article{
width:652px;
height:179px;
background-color:#FFF;}
```

Comment: To clarify, which part of the layout are you having trouble achieving? The ad on the right? The contents inside each div?

Comment: All of the top, everything in the gray box. The right side, I haven't even coded yet, which I'm having trouble with as well.

Answer (score 0):

By default div elements are on top of each other, so if you want your subscribe section to be on the right you will have to float it right.

And wrap your left div's in a parent container div. That's the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

`#interview` and `#article` are larger than `.wrap` which is not what you want !

Plus, add to your CSS:

```
#interview{
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#article{
    position: relative;
}
```

This would help you !

Answer (score 0):

For this type of layout try to use a GRID SYSTEM layout.
Visit [960GS](http://960.gs/) website for help.